# Perceptron in Matlab with different activation functions

Tags: matlab, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, perceptron

I'm about to learn how Neural Network works. Let me be clear about this: I don't want to use any built in functions. I want, for my understanding, build a own perceptron from beginning. For an example I built a perceptron according to this schematic:

[image: Scheme of the Perceptron]

All neurons have identity functions except neuron 6 and 7. Those two neurons should have logistic functions 1/(1+e^(-x)). Neuron 1 is connected directly to 6 and Neuron 2 is connected directly to the Output Neuron 8.

My problem is now how to implement this special situation. I get correct values in C when all neurons are identities. But as soon if I want to implement the logistic functions on 6 and 7, I get wrong values.

Is it possible to find a general algorithm to cover these special situations? (Different activating functions, hopping over layer, feedbacks).

I like it to have it as general and mathematical as possible. Workarounds should be avoided!

The code:

```
clear;
% Input Layer
o1 = 1;
o2 = 1;
o3 = 1;

% Hidden Layer
o4 = 0;
o5 = 0;
o6 = 0;
o7 = 0;

% Output Layer
o8 = 0;

% Init the Inputvektor:
O = [o1,o2,o3,o4,o5,o6,o7,o8];
C = 0;

% Weight Matrix:

     % 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
  W = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0; % 1
      0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1 ; % 2  
      0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0 ; % 3
      0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0 ; % 4
      0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0 ; % 5
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 ; % 6
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 ; % 7
      0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; % 8

% 3 Layer = 3 Iterations:

for c = 0:2

% Calculate Outputvektor (t+1):
A = O*W;

% Assing new Input vektor:
O = A;

% This seems not correct:
% I want to have Identityfunctions on all Neurons except on Neurons 6 and 7
% However I do not get the correct solutions at the end
O(6) = 1/(1+exp(-O(6)));
O(7) = 1/(1+exp(-O(7)));

% Result of the whole Net:
C = C + O
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested, I have found the solution by myself:

```
clear;
% Input Layer
o1 = 0.1;
o2 = 0.1;
o3 = 0.1;

% Hidden Layer
o4 = 0;
o5 = 0;
o6 = 0;
o7 = 0;

% Output Layer
o8 = 0;

Org = [o1,o2,o3,o4,o5,o6,o7,o8];
O = Org;
C = 0;


   % 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
W = [0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0; % 1
    0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1 ; % 2  
    0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0 ; % 3
    0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0 ; % 4
    0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0 ; % 5
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 ; % 6
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1 ; % 7
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; % 8

for c = 0:2

 A = O*W;

 O = A;

 O(6) = 1/(1+exp(-1*O(6)));
 O(7) = 1/(1+exp(-1*O(7)));

  % THIS IS THE SOLUTION:
  O = O + Org
end
```